# Trying to save image to aws s3 sub folder using aws lambda with nodejs runtime

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, serverless

I have a bucket in aws s3, named BUCKET and a folder inside bucket named images. I want to fetch and image, then resize and put it inside BUCKET/images, using s3.putobject.

Below code uses BUCKET which contains only root bucket name. That is, BUCKET. I need BUCKET/images. When I try to give key as images/originalKey , it won't work.

If I give BUCKET/images also won't work.

I am using this code in aws lamda services.

```
 S3.getObject({Bucket: BUCKET, Key:  `images/${originalKey}`}).promise()
.then(data => Sharp(data.Body)
  .resize(width, height)
  .toFormat('png')
  .toBuffer()
)
.then(buffer => S3.putObject({
    Body: buffer,
    Bucket: BUCKET,
    ContentType: 'image/png',
    Key: key,
  }).promise()
)
.then(() => callback(null, {
    statusCode: '301',
    headers: {'location': `${URL}/${key}`},
    body: '',
  })
)
.catch(err => callback(err))
```

Comment: `Bucket: BUCKET, Key: \`images/${originalKey}\`` is correct, but you say "it doesn't work."  In what sense does it not work? Is there an error?

Comment: If I use this way, my image resize api giving internal server error.

Comment: @user1197250 then post the error with full stacktrace

Comment: API giving error "message"":"Internal server error". Cloud watch says ""Unable to import module 'index': Error" .  If I remove that path and use root bucket, then it works fine. But I need to resize images in sub folder.

Comment: `Unable to import module 'index'` sounds like a syntax error in your code (and there should be more, in the stack trace).  You'll have to write it either the way I've shown, above, or `Key: 'images/' + originalKey`.

Comment: I updated my code above. If I remove the image path and use root bucket , the it works fine and no syntax error.